# SQL Server 2005 Lock Pages in Memory on 32-bit system

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, 32-bit, virtual-memory, awe

On a 32-bit Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition SP2, I'm debating the pros and cons of /3gb + AWE + Locked Pages for SQL Server 2005 Standard SP3 CU4.

The system only has 4GB of physical memory, however the developer's IIS service seems to be causing high page-outs for SQL Server.

The solution must be limited to existing hardware and software limitations. (32-bit OS, 32-bit SQL Server, 4GB of physical RAM).  The second challenge is that the server is not domain joined so using local workstation credentials to limit LPIM's scope (A highly recommended configurable option for LPIM) may affect application communication between physical servers.

Thanks to @PaulWhiteNZ's response on #sqlhelp there is some [empirical](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2007/01/11/awe-and-3gb-an-empirical-picture.aspx) data on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, if SQL Server and IIS are fighting over memory you need a separate server. Which is always good thing anyway: IIS and SQL Server have different resource requirements and usage patterns.

If you lock memory you'll just make things worse for IIS.

Comment: +1. The only proper way to handle that is to give it more memory AND REINSTALL AS 64 BIT. Point. End of life for the 32  bit address range. Or get two servers - and have the same problem posibly later again. Like pretty soon.

Comment: This hardware is 32-bit only and physically limited to 4GB of memory.  The question is about the implications of LMIP and AWE for 32-bit systems.

I'd love to spilt this into two physical servers and use 64-bit OS and SQL Server, however I must first prove my case to the development and management teams.